# How to subtract from cells making their value 0 and moving on to the next row?

Tags: vba, excel

How can I subtract values from cells while not making them get negative values?

For example.

I have a cell with 100 in a row. 
And another with 200 in the next row.

I use a CommandButton to subtract 105 from those rows. However, I want to use the FIFO (First In, First Out) principle and subtract from the cell with 100 first until it reaches 0 and only then, subtract from the one with 200.

This is what I have so far.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 'Guardar Carbonação
Dim LastRow As Long, CR As Long, ws As Worksheet, CR2 As Long, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("Carbonação")
    Set ws3 = Sheets("STOCK Sticks")
        LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        CR = ws3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        ws.Range("A" & LastRow).Value = Int((99999999 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 8) 'ID Carbonação
        ws.Range("B" & LastRow).Value = ComboBox1.Text 'Fabricante
        ws.Range("C" & LastRow).Value = TextBox25.Text 'Lote Membranas
        ws.Range("D" & LastRow).Value = Sheets("STOCK Sticks").Range("A" & CR) 'ID Sticks
        ws.Range("E" & LastRow).Value = TextBox2.Text 'Nº Carbonação
        ws.Range("F" & LastRow).Value = TextBox3.Text 'Densidade Total / Carbonação
        ws.Range("G" & LastRow).Value = TextBox1.Text 'TETRA
        ws.Range("H" & LastRow).Value = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm") 'Data / Hora introdução

    Set ws2 = Sheets("STOCK Membranas")
        CR2 = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1
            If ws2.Range("H" & CR2).Value = 0 Then
                CR2 = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                ws2.Range("H" & CR2).Value = ws2.Range("H" & CR2) - 4
            ElseIf ws2.Range("H" & CR2).Value > 0 Then
                   CR2 = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1
                   ws2.Range("H" & CR2).Value = ws2.Range("H" & CR2) - 4
            End If


ComboBox1.Value = Null
TextBox25.Value = Null
TextBox1.Value = Null
TextBox2.Value = Null
TextBox3.Value = Null
End Sub
```

Comment: why are we subtracting -4 here "ws2.Range("H" & CR2).Value = ws2.Range("H" & CR2) - 4".

Comment: @ApurvPawar in this case the value we will be subtracting will always be 4 no matter what. But I am going to need it later on, so I'm trying to get it done right now.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have a problem like this start from the smallest possible example and make it work. E.g., something like this:

[image]

Now the idea is to substract a value (let's say `320`) from the cell in `A1`, then the rest from the `B1` and etc. At the end you should have something like this:

[image]

Now the funny part - work until you do not achieve picture 2 from picture 1. The simplest possible option is with using a variable for `substractValue` and decrease it with the value of the cell. Once the `substractValue` becomes 0 exit the for-loop:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SubstractMe()

    Dim substractValue  As Double
    Dim myCell          As Range

    Range("A1") = 100
    Range("A2") = 200
    Range("A3") = 300
    Range("A4") = 400

    substractValue = 320

    For Each myCell In Range("A1:A4")
        If myCell - substractValue < 0 And substractValue > 0 Then
            substractValue = substractValue - myCell
            myCell = 0
        Else
            myCell = myCell - substractValue
            Exit For
        End If
    Next myCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Do I have to set the values for that range?
I'm using values that have already been placed inside the sheets I need.

Comment: @Barbaaz - no, you do not have to. I have done it, in order to make sure that it works, because during the tests I have executed the code multiple times.

Comment: So I can use the variables I have in my code at the moment and use a loop like you did?

Comment: for some reason I can't tag you. I'm sorry to bother a little longer but I am quite new to VBA. I learned VB in High School but haven't used it in years, so I'm a bit stranded.
Should I ditch the "If" part of my code?

Comment: @Barbaaz - to be honest, your code is a bit of a small mess. I do not understand the `-4` and `-1` parts, thus I cannot advise there. Concerning tagging, you cannot tag me under my answer, I get notification for every post.

Comment: Yeah. I figured it would be gory. I'm going to try and explain what I need to do. I need to develop a "small" stock management software inside Excel. And since I need to use FIFO, I need to constantly jump from row to row until the values are 0. That's why you see the `-1`. As for the `-4`, that's the default value that will be subtracted from that range.